# The 20 newsgroups dataset comprises around 18000 newsgroups posts, while sklearn loads only about half of the dataset, why is that?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The [20 newsgroups dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) comprises around 18000 newsgroups posts on 20 topics split in two subsets.

while sklearn loads only about half of the dataset

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
>>> newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
>>> newsgroups_train.filenames.shape
(11314,)
```

why does sklearn only loads about half of the dataset?

Comment: Because you're looking at the training data set. The rest will be held out for testing.

Comment: @JoeHalliwell  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching the `train` subset of the data. The other chunk of the data set (`test`) is held out for testing purposes.